# Qualifiers on =delete methods

Tags: c++, methods, qualifiers

When marking special methods as `=delete` do the qualifiers of the method come into play ?
In other words are:

```
inline constexpr myClass(const myClass&) noexcept = delete;
```

and

```
myClass(const myClass&) = delete;
```

equivalent ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As often it is, it's usually to just try it and ask the compiler:

```
class myClass {
    inline constexpr myClass(const myClass&) noexcept = delete;
    myClass(const myClass&) = delete;
};

int main() {
    return 0;
}


1 bla.cpp|4 col 5 error| ‘myClass::myClass(const myClass&)’ cannot be overloaded with ‘constexpr myClass::myClass(const myClass&)’
2 bla.cpp|3 col 22 error| note: previous declaration ‘constexpr myClass::myClass(const myClass&)
```

So yes, they are the same function. You can try

```
myClass x;
auto y = x;
```

with each to ensure the copy constructor was removed. This should make sense - the qualifiers are not a new declaration, they just qualify an existing one.

Comment: So it would in fact be better (for clarity) to just write the second choice (just `myClass(const myClass&) = delete;`) I presume ?

Comment: @A.D that's an opinion, but I agree, for me it is.

Comment: And so, when declaring methods `=default`, the qualifiers given have in a similar way no impact ?

Comment: @A.D Indeed. You just can't declare the same function or method twice with different qualifiers.

Comment: But in the event I were to do ``` constexpr myClass(const myClass&) noexcept = default;``` would this add the constexpr qualifier to the default copy constructor ? Or would it simply be ignored in favor of the qualifiers of the default method ?

Comment: @A.D That's a different question, but yes. A bit harder to check that - declare a `constexpr` default constructor, copy constructor, and the two initialization statements in my test program. Miss one and the compiler will complain. Same deal - compiler knows best.

Comment: Asking a compiler is rarely a good way to determining what is valid C++ code. You need instead to consult the language standard.

Comment: @CodyGray sounds meticulous. I'm sure the question would benefit from your standard based answer.